# How to punctuate abbreviation of a hyphenated middle name (Charles-Moore) on a plaque?

Tags: punctuation

How do you punctuate the abbreviation of a hyphenated middle name (Charles-Moore) on a plaque? Some thoughts include: C-M ; C - M ; C.-M. ; C. - M.

Comment: A hyphenated middle name? That's a first (for me that is). I would either do C. M. or just C. and assume the contraction includes Moore.

Comment: To TsSkTo -- This was a first for me, as well. I appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find a rule for this in the New Oxford Style Manual (2012), although the book gives the following rules for initials:

> Initials before a surname are separated by full points, with a space after each: 
>   
>   
> *J. S. Bach     -      E. H. Shepard    -      Hunter S. Thompson*
>   
>   
> although some modern designs, particualrly those of newspapers, omit
>   the full points and spaces: 
>   
>   
> *MR James  - PJ Harvey -   George W Bush*
>   
>   
> Normally, names given entirely in initials have points but no spaces
>   (J.A.S., E.H.S., J.R.R.T.). When people are commonly known by their
>   free-standing initials, these forms have neither points nor spaces
>   (FRD, LBJ).

The general approach is supported by Rabinowitz and Vogel (The Manual of Scientific Style).

The Chicago Manual of Style (16th Ed, 2010) states that:

> If two or more initials are used as an abbreviation for an entire name, no
>   periods are needed. 
>   
>   
> *Kennedy and Johnson soon became known as JFK and LBJ.*

The compilers go on to state clearly:

> Initials standing for a hyphenated given name should also be hyphenated.
>   
>   *Jean Paul Sartre; J.-P. Sartre; Sartre*

However, this applies specifically to French names used in a US-English context, and they go on to say:

> Since there is considerable variation in French usage, the guidelines and
>   examples above merely represent the most common forms.

If cultural differences in approach are significant factors in making a choice, and linking orthography to common usage isn't sufficient to allow a sensible decision to be made, I would suggest looking at examples of usage in context.

For instance, the Wellcome Library [abbreviates Kraft-Ebbing to **KE**](https://wellcomelibrary.org/item/b18887223). This would seem to be archiving shorthand;

the Journal of the History of Ideas Vol 62, No 1 abbreviates Kraft-Ebbing to **K-E**
[image: From: Journal of the History of Ideas Volume 62, Number 1, January 2001 pp. 185-192] 

which would seem to fit the academic style of this journal;

and the Austrian Biographical Encyclopedia (Österreichische Biographische Lexikon 1815-1950) [abbreviates Kraft-Ebbing to **K.-E.**](http://www.biographien.ac.at/oebl/oebl_K/Krafft-Ebing_Richard_1840_1902.xml) which is the most formal version of the three. Given the intended use, assuming maximum formality, I would personally go with **C.-M.**.

Comment: Thanks very much for this information. After I posted this question here, I had found the Chicago Manual of Style guidance. It is nice to have you second this advice.